# how to create a Job object when writing Flink dataset to hdfs

Tags: apache-flink

I want to write some dataset to hive. I tried hive jdbc, but it doesn`t support batchExecute. So I changed to write it to hdfs, then generate hive table.

I tried using following code to write hdfs:

```
package test;

import org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.FlatMapFunction;
import org.apache.flink.api.java.DataSet;
import org.apache.flink.api.java.ExecutionEnvironment;
import org.apache.flink.api.java.hadoop.mapreduce.HadoopOutputFormat;
import org.apache.flink.api.java.tuple.Tuple2;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.flink.fs.s3hadoop.shaded.org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.flink.fs.s3presto.shaded.org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.flink.fs.s3presto.shaded.org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat;
import org.apache.flink.util.Collector;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final ExecutionEnvironment env = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
        DataSet<String> text = env.fromElements(
                "Who's there?",
                "I think I hear them. Stand, ho! Who's there?");

            DataSet<Tuple2<String, Integer>> hadoopResult = text
                .flatMap(new LineSplitter())
                .groupBy(0)
                .sum(1);
            //job and jobConf is null,I do not know how to initialize them (new)
        Job job = null;
        Job jobConf = null;
        HadoopOutputFormat<String, Integer> hadoopOF =
                  new HadoopOutputFormat<String, Integer>(
                    new TextOutputFormat<String, Integer>(), job
                  );
                hadoopOF.getConfiguration().set("mapreduce.output.textoutputformat.separator", " ");
                TextOutputFormat.setOutputPath(jobConf, new Path("hdfs://somewhere/"));
                hadoopResult.output(hadoopOF);
    }

     public static class LineSplitter implements FlatMapFunction<String, Tuple2<String, Integer>> {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 3100297611484689639L;
            public void flatMap(String line, Collector<Tuple2<String, Integer>> out) {
                for (String word : line.split(" ")) {
                    out.collect(new Tuple2<String, Integer>(word, 1));
                }
            }
        }
}
```

but there are many compile errors. All the codes are copied from official site and 
stitching these codes.

My question:
how to create a Job and Jobconf Object and then write datasets to hdfs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will find a [complete example](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/batch/hadoop_compatibility.html#complete-hadoop-wordcount-example) in the documentation.

To create a Job:

```
Job job = Job.getInstance();
```

I don't think you need the Jobconf object -- seems like you could use the Job object in both places.